# flutter program work okay on chrome, but cannot work correctly on web server

Tags: google-chrome, flutter, web, dart, server

I'm pretty new to flutter, and wrote the following flutter program to get the client IP address and location. I'm calling "http://ip-api.com/json" for IP address and location information. The program works okay by using device "chrome" and "web server", I can print client's location on the page.
.
When I deployed to github webpage or firebase hosting , and the program  shows "loading circle" for ever. It seems that the program cannot get the ip address after it was deployed to the github web server (or other web server).

I found the program throw "XMLHTTPRequest Error" once i deployed it to Github html page or firebase hosting.  It works fine on the local web server or chrome.  any suggestion on that?  Thanks a lot.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class IP_info{
  final String IP;
  final String city;
  final String ZIP;
  final String st_code;
  final String state_name;
  final String country_code;
  final String country_name;

  IP_info({this.IP, this.city, this.st_code,this.ZIP, 
     this.state_name,this.country_code,this.country_name});

  factory IP_info.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    return IP_info(
      IP:json['query'],
      ZIP:json['zip'],
      city:json['city'],
      country_code:json['countryCode'],
      st_code:json['region'],
      country_name:json['country_name'],
      state_name:json['regionName'],
    );
  }

}
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
      title: 'Covid 19 cases near you',
      home: MyApp()
  ),
  );
}



class MyApp extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState()  => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  bool _isLoading = false;
  IP_info ip_info;

  @override
  void initState() {
     _isLoading=true;
    _getPublicIP();
  }

_getPublicIP() async {
    try {

      const url = 'http://ip-api.com/json';

      final response = await http.get(url);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        ip_info = IP_info.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
        print(ip_info.toString());

        setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
        });
        }
      else {
        // The request failed with a non-200 code
        print(response.statusCode);
        print(response.body);
      }



    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Testing IP address'),    ),
        body: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          child: _isLoading? Center(
              child: Column(children: [
                CircularProgressIndicator(),
                SizedBox(height: 10,),
                Text("Loading your location infomation ...", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blueAccent),),
              ]
              )
          )
              : new Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center ,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget> [
              Text('You are in ${ip_info.city} ${ip_info.state_name} ',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,),
              ),

            ],
          ),
        )
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because of the service worker file generated only for the release build. The `{ credentials: 'include' }` part of service work file breaks all requests without `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` or with that of value `*` which is all public APIs.

There is an [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/51252) on that, and it is said to be fixed in master which has not been released yet. So some workarounds you can do currently is to remove the `credentials` part manually after every build or to unregister the service worker.

Here's how you can remove that part if you still want to use service worker. There should be a `flutter_service_worker.js` file inside the `build/web` folder. You will find that credentials part as the second argument of the `fetch` function. You can remove that argument. But the bad thing about this is you have to remove that part manually every time after building, which is not programmatic or effective.

The best way for this problem is to completely unregister the service worker. You can do that by, removing this script part from the `web/index.html` file.

```html
<script>
      if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
        window.addEventListener("load", function() {
          navigator.serviceWorker.register("/flutter_service_worker.js");
        });
      }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Frenco for taking a look at this.   I added "CircularProgressIndicator()" function to the code (please see above). But the code are still not working after i deployed to the web server.      I am using master channel for flutter. Can you advise which program i can remove "credentials: 'include'"  ?  Thanks for the instructions.

Comment: Hi Frenco,  I commented out the service worker section in web/index.html file, but I still get a blank page once i deployed the code to github html or firebase hosting.

Comment: I think you are right. it is maybe related to some setting issues.

Comment: @JoeZhou You rebuilt again after the `web/index.html` file was updated right? Because if not, you have to.

Comment: Thanks Frenco!  Once i rebuilt  with "flutter build web", the web/index.html got regenerated with "Service Worker" section. I'm noob here.  Is "flutter build web" the right command to build ?

Comment: I found the program throw "XMLHTTPRequest Error" once i deployed it to Github html page.  It works fine on the local web server or chrome.  any suggestion on that?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you have a repo? I could review and help if you have.

Comment: Thanks!   I switched to https://geolocation-db.com/json/ (instead of using 'http://ip-api.com/json) to get the location information of the client's node, and it works! I think it is related to the server side.   I think it may be related to the web request has to be https instead of http.  thanks again for helping on this !

Answer (score 0):

I switched to geolocation-db.com/json (instead of using 'ip-api.com/json) to get the location information of the client's node, and it works! I think it is related to the server side. I think it may be related to the web request has to be https instead of http.